# Testing a function call with a simulated button click but code coverage saying its not being tested

Tags: angular

I have set up a test to simulate clicking a button which calls the `toggleMenuButton` function however my code coverage shows the line `this.showMenu = !this.showMenu;` in red and is saying its not being tested. Am I missing something?

Nav.component.ts

```
showMenu = false; 

toggleMenuButton() {
  this.showMenu = !this.showMenu; // this line is in red
}
```

Nav.component.spec.ts

```
describe('NavComponent', () => {
  let component: NavComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<NavComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ NavComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NavComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should open the menu button when clicked', () => {
    spyOn(component, 'toggleMenuButton');
    const btn = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.navmenu')).nativeElement;
     btn.click();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(component.toggleMenuButton).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a test case to test the `toggleMenuButton` function.

```js
it('should toggle the menu when toggleMenuButton is called', () => {
    component.showMenu = false; // Not required if you are setting showMenu to false in your component initially.
    component.toggleMenuButton();
    expect(component.showMenu).toBeTruthy();

    component.showMenu = true;
    component.toggleMenuButton();
    expect(component.showMenu).toBeFalsy();
});
```